# Regex with multiple square brackets

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed, replace

I'm working with some transcriptions and I've struggled with their normalization. Some of them have square brackets within other square brackets to specify the different noises / sound events that can be found when listening to the corresponding audio file. This is an example of one file's line:

```
U012_W038 [other_speech_adult: [laughter] yeah you can you can read [undefined] tomorrow] [other_speech_adult: are you recording me now] this is annoying eh [noise] [noise_bkgspeech/]
```

In every line the format corresponds to

```
<audio file reference> <transcription>
```

My ideal output would be:

1. Get the text that is not enclosed by any square brackets: e.g: "this is annoying eh"
2. Extract the text that's inside of square brackets only if ":" is found. The text to catch would be the one after the colon. e.g: yeah you can you can read

The output should look something similar to this:

```
U012_W038 yeah you can you can read tomorrow are you recording me now this is annoying eh
```

I tried to solve this problem using sed, but I wouldn't mind trying perl or any other text processing tool. My closest attempt so far is:

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*]//g'
```

Do you think there's a way to solve this out by coding or it's to be by a manual checking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the maximum level of nested brackets 2? I mean is literally _square brackets within other square brackets_, or can it be _square brackets within other square brackets within other square brackets..._? From you example it seems the answer is that the level of nesting is at most 2.

Comment: The general problem of arbitrary nesting cannot be handled in regex. If you only need, say, two levels of nesting, that could probably be done, but you'd need a catalog of the annotations which are not part of the dialog. We can make a regex to remove `[laughter]` and `[noise]` etc but presumably there are more of these in the material. And/or specify a rule, like a single alphabetic + underscore token in square brackets can be deleted, whereas other square brackets should be removed alone `s/\[[a-z_]\+\]\|\[\|]//g`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. After checking the transcriptions, I noticed that there are some lines that have only a pair square brackets, and other that have two ,as the example (and that's indeed the maximum level of nested brackets

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, something like

```
perl -pe 's/\[[a-z_]+:|\[[a-z_\/]+\]|\]//g' file
```

This can be easily expressed in `sed` too, but the regex variations differ between dialects. If you have `sed -E` or `sed -r`, you could probably use this regex verbatim.

Comment: Great, I was taking a totally wrong turn, and it was so easy instead. However you should include `/` somewhere, as the last piece to delete is `[noise_bkgspeech/]`.

Answer (score 1):

This version

```
perl -pe 's/\[[^]:]+\]//g;s/\[[^]:]*:([^]:]+)*\]/\1/g;s/ +/ /g' file
```

detects non-paired brackets.

Comment: Given the OP, unpaired brackets probably mean ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command if your file is named `audio`:

```
sed 's/\[\([^]]*:\)//g; s/\[[^]]*]//g; s/]//g; s/  */ /g' audio
```

This gave me on your example :

`U012_W038 yeah you can you can read tomorrow are you recording me now this is annoying eh`

Step by step this command does:

- `sed 's/\[\([^]]*:\)//g'`: deletes everything between `[` and `:` included
- `sed 's/\[[^]]*]//g'`: deletes everything between `[` and `]` included.
- `sed 's/]//g'`: deletes the remaining `]`
- `sed 's/  */ /g'`: deletes all consecutive blanks.

Comment: `sed` is a scripting language; you can combine all these commands in a single script instead of in four separate processes.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I've corrected my answer accordingly to your comment.